# Problems with GMP library and C++

Tags: c++, gmp

First I included gmp.h, and when I compiled, it said that it didn't find the functions ( float function, mpf_t ). Then I found a page where it said that you should include gmpxx.h for C++ projects, but when compiling it just says that the compiler can't find gmpxx. Wouldn't that be installed with GMP?

Comment: Probably not. Some people just want to write C.

Comment: Build GMP with `--enable-cxx`.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer and not comment, so I can make it the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build GMP with --enable-cxx and it should work.